# Dimension of an affine variety

Tags: geometry

Supponing that $K$ is an infinite field. We indicate $\operatorname{in}(I)$ as the ideal generated by the leading monomials of the polinomials in the ideal $I$, after fixing a term order. Suppose that $V(I)$ is the affine variety generated by $I$ and that $I(V)$ is the ideal formed by all the polynomials that are zero on $V$. How can I prove that if $\dim(V(\operatorname{in}(I(V))))=0$ then also $\dim(V(I))$ is zero? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two ways of doing this. The heavy machinery way is to use that the passage from an ideal to its initial ideal is a flat deformation, and dimension is one of the invariants under deformation, meaning that the initial ideal and the original ideal must have the same dimension.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me also the other method you know?